# Prevent concatenate VBA from expanding column when running code and saving .txt file to desktop without opening Notepad?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that concatenates 6 cells from column A that loops until a blank cell is reached. The output is copied into range `B2:B20` and then exported as a `.txt` which automatically opens when exporting.

How do I:

1. prevent the code from expanding column B when executing (this hides the export button in column C and requires you to scroll to export which isn't too bad but I would like to automate this as best as I can)
2. how to have the `.txt` file saved to the desktop while not opening Notepad when this is executed? I've tried removing parts (like opening Notepad upon export with Shell) and adjusting the code to prevent column resize when concatenating (playing with resize, .Resize(srCount), but I only receive errors

[image: Error when running]

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Call Sheet1.ConcatGroupsOfCells
    Call Sheet1.CrText
    
End Sub

Sub ConcatGroupsOfCells()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Concatenate Groups of Cells"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2" ' "C1"
    Const CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 6 ' 15
    Const CONCAT_DELIMITER As String = " OR "
    Const COUNT_BLANKS As Boolean = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "All cells are empty!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    Dim scell As Range, sStr As String, dStr As String, n As Long
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        If COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
        sStr = CStr(scell.Value)
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            If Not IsFound Then IsFound = True
            If Not COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
            If Len(dStr) = 0 Then
                dStr = sStr
            Else
                dStr = dStr & CONCAT_DELIMITER & sStr
            End If
        End If
        If n = CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT Then
            dcell.Value = dStr
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
            dStr = vbNullString
            n = 0
        End If
    Next scell
    
    If Len(dStr) > 0 Then
        dcell.Value = dStr
    Else
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(-1)
    End If
    
    If Not IsFound Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With dcell
        .Offset(1).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row).Clear
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
 
End Sub
Sub CrText()


Dim c00            As Variant
Dim textFilePath   As String
Dim lngCounter     As Long
Dim FF             As Integer


textFilePath = CStr(VBA.CurDir) & "\ScanError.txt"


FF = VBA.FreeFile
c00 = Range("B2:B20")

Open textFilePath For Output As #FF
    For lngCounter = LBound(c00, 1) To UBound(c00, 1)
        Print #FF, Join(Application.Index(c00, lngCounter, 0), vbTab)
    Next
Close #FF
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & textFilePath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

---

Here is the new code I tried using that was the above code but edited (bold parts are what was removed)

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Call Sheet1.ConcatGroupsOfCells
    Call Sheet1.CrText
    
End Sub

Sub ConcatGroupsOfCells()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Concatenate Groups of Cells"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2" ' "C1"
    Const CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 6 ' 15
    Const CONCAT_DELIMITER As String = " OR "
    Const COUNT_BLANKS As Boolean = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "All cells are empty!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        **Set srg = .Resize(srCount)**
    End With
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    Dim scell As Range, sStr As String, dStr As String, n As Long
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        If COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
        sStr = CStr(scell.Value)
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            If Not IsFound Then IsFound = True
            If Not COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
            If Len(dStr) = 0 Then
                dStr = sStr
            Else
                dStr = dStr & CONCAT_DELIMITER & sStr
            End If
        End If
        If n = CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT Then
            dcell.Value = dStr
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
            dStr = vbNullString
            n = 0
        End If
    Next scell
    
    If Len(dStr) > 0 Then
        dcell.Value = dStr
    Else
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(-1)
    End If
    
    If Not IsFound Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With dcell
        .Offset(1).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row).Clear
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
 
End Sub
Sub CrText()


Dim c00            As Variant
Dim textFilePath   As String
Dim lngCounter     As Long
Dim FF             As Integer


textFilePath = CStr(VBA.CurDir) & "\ScanError.txt"


FF = VBA.FreeFile
c00 = Range("B2:B20")

Open textFilePath For Output As #FF
    For lngCounter = LBound(c00, 1) To UBound(c00, 1)
        Print #FF, Join(Application.Index(c00, lngCounter, 0), vbTab)
    Next
Close #FF
**Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & textFilePath, vbNormalFocus**
End Sub
```

Comment: remove `.EntireColumn.AutoFit` and `Shell "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & textFilePath, vbNormalFocus`

Comment: Thank you! It all works, but how do I ensure that it gets exported to desktop instead of the documents folder?

Comment: replace `CStr(VBA.CurDir)` with the correct directory string in `textFilePath = CStr(VBA.CurDir) & "\ScanError.txt"`

Comment: Could also copy the values to a new workbook and save it as a textfile instead of exporting it. As for the desktop part, you'll have to adjust `CStr(VBA.CurDir)` To `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")`